# Are there Latin squares with no repeats on the diagonal not of the form 2y+x+1(mod n)?

Tags: matrices, modular-arithmetic, latin-square, group-homomorphism

I am looking for a certain kind of latin square (nxn).
Rules:
No repeats in any column or row (Definition of Latin Square)
No repeats in any diagonal including others than the main diagonal.
So $\begin{matrix} 1&2\\2&1 \end{matrix}$ would not qualify nor would $\begin{matrix} 1&2&(3)&4\\4&(3)&2&1\\2&1&4&3\\3&4&1&2 \end{matrix}$

---

So far I have found that no solution exists for $1\lt n\lt 5$ or for $n=6$.
For $n=1$ we have the trivial solution: $\begin{matrix} 1 \end{matrix} $.
For $n=5$ we have $2$ solutions 
$\begin{matrix} 1&2&3&4&5\\3&4&5&1&2\\5&1&2&3&4\\2&3&4&5&1\\4&5&1&2&3\end{matrix}$               
$\begin{matrix} 1&2&3&4&5\\4&5&1&2&3\\2&3&4&5&1\\5&1&2&3&4\\3&4&5&1&2\end{matrix}$
and homomorphisms of these for a total of $240$ solutions.

---

For larger odd dimensions the $n=5$ set of solutions can be generalized bacause the same pattern visible in the $5x5$ works as a $7x7,11x11,13x13,17x17,19x19,...$ so we have for n$\ge$5 where $n$ is odd and $n$ is not a multiple of $3$, we always have at least $2*n!$ solutions which are the homomorphisms of squares with elements $2y+x+1$(mod n) where $y$ is the row index and $x$ is the column index of each element. So my question is are there any other squares which satisfy these constraints? Ex: any even dimensioned square, or any odd dimensioned square not following these rules.
Any ideas on which way to go next would be appreciated. Including perhaps ideas on how to write a program to solve it. I have found my current solutions simply by method of exhaustion.

Comment: Now I realize this problem is somewhat related to the n-queens problem. It is a generalization of n-queens.

Comment: Your two solutions for $n=5$ seem to be the same if you sort the rows. You are shifting 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 in all rows.

Comment: @CarlosPinzón yes. For the 5x5 the solutions do turn out to be a circular shift of the rows for each row. Nothing in the requirements makes it have to be that way for higher orders though or makes the rows always sortable which comes to the last part of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found more research on this problem:

George Pólya came to the same conclusions I did:

Patrick Hamlyn and Guenter Stertenbrink discovered that the 12x12 board has 454 solutions:

- http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/The12x12QueensProblem/
- http://www.mathpuzzle.com/MAA/36-Chessboard%20Tasks/mathgames_04_11_05.html
- http://www.mathpuzzle.com/MAA/36-Chessboard%20Tasks/12queens.txt

The solved sizes for "n" are contained in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences as:

- https://oeis.org/A168553